# How do you inspect a javascript timeout using Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I suspect I have an issue with a timeout function in javascript that triggers a refresh. Is there a way in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to view what timeouts have been registered?

Edit: I guess I wasn't clear, is there a way to view the list of timeout callbacks or their status? (Timeleft, fired or not, registered function, etc....)

Comment: All I've found so far is that you can get the timer's ID. http://justpowered.de/blog/misc/javascript-timer-and-stack-trace-debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

If you name all the timeouts you can view them in firebug.

```
var t1 = setTimeout(...,...);
```

Then in the console you can just type in `t1` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Or type `console.log(t1)` into the console and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just use `console.log('your message here');` to track your function executions.

Call it at the beginning of a function and you will know that that function is being called.

If you place it in the function being called by the `setTimeout`, you will know how many times it triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to from your javascript send messages to the firebug console.

should be as easy as console.debug()

so

```
setTimeout(
    function()
    {
        console.debug("EVENT!");
    },
    1500
);
```

see: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API